# How to get get rid of baddua

Tags: hadith, islamic-basis, curse

I want something very eagerly and my mom cursed me that no matter what you want you won't get it, she gave me baddua and I am so scared, how do I get rid of that please help

Comment: If what you want is halal, I don't see why the dua should have any ill effect on you.

Comment: You should be more worried about your mom, as a failed curse goes back to the one how did the cast. Hopefully, it was not a true curse but only a bad tongue.